# PostgreSQL discrepancy between sequences listed by the information_schema.sequences and pg_sequences / pg_class views

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I'm upgrading an application dependency on Liquibase to a more recent version of the library and, in doing so, have stubbed my toe on a behavioral difference.  In my application I have code that enumerates the sequences in a database and that code, when unit tested, is returning fewer sequences when using the newer version of Liquibase.  Upon manual examination of the DB(s) I have found that, with the newer version of Liquibase, some of my sequences are listed in the `information_schema.sequences` view and some are not.  All seem to be listed when I query the `pg_class` view with the condition `WHERE relkind = 'S'` or simply query `pg_sequences`.  I added some debug output for the Liquibase change sets and found that the syntax for the creation of tables has changed vs. our earlier Liquibase version (3.5.4).  This syntax changes seems to be related to whether or not a sequence associated with a `SERIAL` or, in Liquibase / no-PostgreSQL specific terminology, an `autoIncrement` column is visible in the `information_schema.sequences` view.  Here's what I've found:

**Testing using Liquibase 3.5.4 table creation syntax**

```
=# CREATE TABLE public.my_test_table (id SERIAL NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(50), CONSTRAINT PK_MY_TEST_TABLE PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE

=# CREATE SEQUENCE my_test_seq START 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE

=# SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';
       relname        
----------------------
 my_test_table_id_seq
 my_test_seq
(2 rows)

=# select sequence_name from information_schema.sequences;
    sequence_name     
----------------------
 my_test_table_id_seq
 my_test_seq
(2 rows)

=# select sequencename from pg_sequences;
     sequencename     
----------------------
 my_test_table_id_seq
 my_test_seq
(2 rows)
```

**Using Liquibase 4.4.0 table creation syntax**

```
=# CREATE TABLE public.my_test_table (id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(50), CONSTRAINT my_test_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE

=# CREATE SEQUENCE my_test_seq START 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE

=# SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';
       relname        
----------------------
 my_test_table_id_seq
 my_test_seq
(2 rows)

=# select sequence_name from information_schema.sequences;
 sequence_name 
---------------
 my_test_seq
(1 row)

=# select sequencename from pg_sequences;
     sequencename     
----------------------
 my_test_table_id_seq
 my_test_seq
(2 rows)
```

Note the single result querying `information_schema.sequences` above.

The testing here was done on PG 10.14, 12.4, and 12.6 - all of which behave equivalently with these commands.

So, is this a Liquibase bug or a PostgreSQL bug or neither and simply working as expected (to someone other than me anyway)?  Many thanks!

Comment: It is not a bug either at all; it is a different way of doing things. When a column is defined as identity then ***no sequence is created***. That information however can be found in information_schema.view.columns. Look at the column names (in the view) is_identity and the columns identity_...  A [good reference article](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-10-identity-columns/).

Comment: @Belayer: "When a column is defined as identity then ***no sequence is created**." -- Yes it is. ["CREATE TABLE"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)": `GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY [ ( sequence_options ) ]` This clause creates the column as an identity column. It will have an implicit sequence attached to it and the column in new rows will automatically have values from the sequence assigned to it." And the OP clearly states that they get a sequence from Postgres' catalog. ...

Comment: ... And a [quick test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=065bcf1720303d07c1ce7ba96751b0e4) confirms that.

Comment: @stickybit. Got ahead on myself. Meant to say no sequence is entered into the information_schema.sequence view.

Comment: @Belayer: Yes, that's what the OP already found out...

Comment: I do not know but I can *speculate*. **Maybe** it's got something to do with the standard(s). Since `IDENTITY` is a standard thing and `information_schema` is too, there's somewhere something in the standard(s) that dictate that even if `IDENTITY` is implemented via sequences in the background, it's not supposed to expose that sequences via the `information_schema`. But again, that's pure **speculation**. So far I wasn't able to find any documentation backing that. ...

Comment: ...  (The only thing I can recommend is just not to use the `information_schema` but always prefer the vendor specific catalog if available. It's more accurate, it's more detailed. But I don't know if that's of any help here because I don't know Liquibase and whether it even supports that.)

Comment: So, FWIW, I can easily work around the issue by querying the PG-specific views and have tweaked my implementation to do so.  The only reason Liquibase is relevant here is that it was responsible for creating the sequence(s) in question as a side effect of table creation thus the change in their table creation syntax triggered the issue for me.  I'm the one explicitly querying for sequences in my code and so I have working code now.  I'm just curious about the discrepancy in the meta data views.  Thanks to everyone for your responses!